# Array of objects in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Beginner question:

How to make an Array of objects from a Struct in Crystal? Or how to make an array of objects in Crystal? I am trying to emulate the go code.

```
struct Book 
   def initialize(
     @Id : Int32,
     @Title : String,
     @Author : String, 
     @Desc : String
   )
   end
 end

 books = [] of Int32 | String <--- This is wrong
 book1 = Book.new(1, "Hello", "Me", "This is a test.")


GO CODE: 

type Book struct {
   Id     int    `json:"id"`
   Title  string `json:"title"`
   Author string `json:"author"`
   Desc   string `json:"desc"`
}

var Books = []models.Book{
   {
       Id:     1,
       Title:  "Golang",
       Author: "Gopher",
       Desc:   "A book for Go",
   },
}
```

Changing to a class allows me to return a new object. Which I am sure is the wrong way to make a new object in Crystal? I can then add objects to the array.

```
  class Book 
    def initialize(id : Int32, title : String, author : String, desc : String)
      @id = id
      @title = title
      @author = author
      @desc = desc
    end

    def object 
      {
        @id,
        @title,
        @author,
        @desc
    }
    end 

  end


  books = [] of Book <--- HOW TO SET ARRAY OF OBJECTS ON THE TYPE?
  book1 = Book.new(1, "Hello", "Me", "This is a test.")
  puts book1.object
  books << book1.object
  puts books
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems really what I wanted, and what was not the same as the struct version in go was an Array of Hashes, which in turn is an Array of Objects, as everything is an Object in Crystal?*.

```
  hash = [] of Hash(Int32, String) # Array of Hashes
  hash0 = {0 => "Jackson0"}
  hash1 = {1 => "Jackson1"}
  hash2 = {2 => "Jackson2"}
  hash3 = {3 => "Jackson3"}

  #Append the hashes to the array

  hash << hash0
  hash << hash1
  hash << hash2
  hash << hash3

OR

  (0..3).each do |i| 
    hash << {i => "Jackson#{i}"}
  end
  RESULT : [{0 => "Jackson0"}, {1 => "Jackson1"}, {2 => "Jackson2"}, {3 => "Jackson3"}]

  # Display them as JSON

  get "/" do
    hash.to_json
  end

RESULT : [{"0":"Jackson0"},{"1":"Jackson1"},{"2":"Jackson2"},{"3":"Jackson3"}]

Which in turn can be queried using hash[0][1] 

RESULT : {"1": "Jackson1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
books = [] of Book
books << book1
```

or you can simply do this, and let Crystal recognise the type:

```
books = [book1]
```

The closest to the original is

```
books = [
  Book.new(1, "Hello", "Me", "This is a test.")
]
```

EDIT: If you need JSON, you need to implement it, as [described](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.4.1/JSON.html#generating-with-to-json) in the documentation. The easiest is to `include JSON::Serializable`:

```
require "json"

module TestBookJSON

  struct Book
    include JSON::Serializable      # <-- this

    def initialize(
      @Id : Int32,
      @Title : String,
      @Author : String,
      @Desc : String
    )
    end
  end

  books = [] of Book
  book1 = Book.new(1, "Hello", "Me", "This is a test.")
  books << book1
  puts books.to_json
  # => [{"Id":1,"Title":"Hello","Author":"Me","Desc":"This is a test."}]

end
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nCDLLAN

I tried this but don't seem to get an array of objects like the Go code makes. Because I guess my struct in Crystal isn't making an object.

Comment: What makes you think you are not getting an array of objects?

Comment: I added another photo to the link above, shows an array of Structs? maybe the terminal is playing tricks on me.

Comment: Every `Book` is a `Struct`, every `Struct` is a `Value`, and every `Value` is an `Object`. ["Everything is an object"](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.4/syntax_and_semantics/everything_is_an_object.html). Saying you have an array of structs instead of array of objects is like saying "I didn't eat any food, I only ate a steak".

Comment: Yep. [Inheritance](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.4/syntax_and_semantics/inheritance.html) is a huge deal in Object-Oriented Programming, which I understand Go (not subscribing to OOP paradigm) does not have, and solves in another way.

Comment: Oh — if you mean "an array where you could put any object", you are correct: this is not it. This is specifically an array of books (all of which are also objects). However, there, too, you are parallel with your Go code: it is also an array of books, not an array of any objects.

Comment: Yeah the Array of books I have is not playing nicely with .to_json as it's expecting a type of "Object". 

I need to make an Array of Objects, which GO is making an Array of Objects using a Struct for the data structure. 

I guess I need to make an Array of Objects, I was using the Struct as a data setup.

Comment: I changed to a class to get the result of an Object output, but not sure what to type for the '[] of Objects'

Comment: As I said before, you do not need "an array of objects". An array of books works just fine. I edited in an example using `#to_json`.